# How to find sudo rights in shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am struggling to work out how to achieve this, as it does not support `-a` parameter on CentOS/RHEL.

My question is : I will get all fields via `passwd -S <user>` on each username and parse the output per your original script. How can I modify script ?

```
#!/bin/bash
passwd -Sa | while read LOGIN PASS_TYPE LAST_CHANGE MIN_AGE MAX_AGE WARN_DAYS INACTIVE_DAYS; do

  # Is this account disabled?
  [[ $PASS_TYPE == LK ]] && DIS="disabled" || DIS=""

  # Can this account sudo?
  #sudo -l -U "$LOGIN" | grep -q not\ allowed && CAN_SUDO="" || CAN_SUDO="sudo"
  sudo -l -U "$LOGIN" | grep -q "(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL\|(ALL) ALL" && CAN_SUDO="sudo" || CAN_SUDO=""

  # Grab misc. info from passwd entry
  IFS=: read _ PASS USERID GROUPID FULLNAME HOMEDIR SH < <(getent passwd "$LOGIN")

  # Grab login time of the latest entry in the lastlog output
  LATEST="$(last ${LOGIN} | head -1 | cut -c40-)"

  echo "${LOGIN}|${FULLNAME}|${USERID}|${LAST_CHANGE}|${MIN_AGE}|${MAX_AGE}|${WARN_DAYS}|${INACTIVE_DAYS}|${DIS}|${CAN_SUDO}|${LATEST}"

done
```

Answer (score 0):

The RHEL variant of `passwd` supports the `-S` option, but you have to use it with a single username at a time.

Therefore, start with a list of users from `/etc/passwd` and then use the `passwd` command on all of them in turn.

```
#!/bin/bash
for user in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd); do
    read -r LOGIN PASS_TYPE LAST_CHANGE MIN_AGE MAX_AGE WARN_DAYS INACTIVE_DAYS CRYPT < <(passwd -S $user)
    # Rest of the processing
done
```

Note that I've added an additional variable named CRYPT to capture the cryptographic information from the end of the line. The INACTIVE_DAYS variable does not get a numeric value without that.